# How to attach new role permissions to iam_role in aws using python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to attach new permissions to the existing IAM role using python boto3. I'm using the **append()** method to attach new permissions to the IAM role but it is not really adding permissions to the role.

**Python:**

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
rolename = ROLENAME
policyname = POLICYNAME

#Get rolepolicy 
response = iam.get_role_policy(RoleName=rolename,PolicyName=policyname)
add_permission = response['PolicyDocument']['Statement']

#Assume json_perm is the  permission that needs to be attached inside Statement block of policydocument.
json_perm = """ {'Action':'*','Resource':'','Effect':'Allow'})""" 

#Attaching new permissions to the role
add_permission.append(json_perm)
print(add_permission)

#Get response after appending
new_response = iam.get_role_policy(RoleName=rolename,PolicyName=policyname)
print(new_response)
```

When printing `add_permission` I'm able to see the new permissions got appended in the policy document.
But I'm not able to see that permission in the AWS console and also after appending If I print `new_response` I'm not able to see the newly added permissions in the output terminal also.

Appending new permissions to the IAM-role doesn't actually do any change to the role..?
How to attach new permissions to the IAM role PolicyDocument using python boto3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Appending new permissions to the IAM-role doesn't actually do any change to the role..?

This does not work, because you are not actually updating the policy at AWS. You are just adding it to a python variable `add_permission`. This **does not automatically translate** to actual changes of the policy at AWS.

For that, you have to use [put_role_policy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.put_role_policy) call to AWS to update the policy.

You can try the following code:

```
#Get rolepolicy 
response = iam.get_role_policy(
    RoleName=rolename,
    PolicyName=policyname)

add_permission = response['PolicyDocument']
#print(add_permission)

#Attaching new permissions to the role
#add_permission.append(json_perm)
#print(add_permission)

# NOT a good idea to allow all actions on all resources
add_permission['Statement'].append({
                       'Action':'*',
                       'Resource':'*',
                       'Effect':'Allow',
                       'Sid': 'AllowAlll'})

response = iam.put_role_policy(
    RoleName=rolename,
    PolicyName=policyname,
    PolicyDocument=json.dumps(add_permission)
)
```